# How to use List component "items" prop in React Semantic UI?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I can't understand how to use "items" property of React Semantic UI "List" component. Is there a way to pass it a function or a component it will use to render every item ?

```
<List items={repos} component={RepoListItem} />;
const RepoListItem = props => {
  return (
    <List.Item>
      <List.Content>{props.full_name}</List.Content>
    </List.Item>
  );
};
```

I look for a property like "component" here that could be used to set a rendering function or component.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass React Components an array of Child components if the parent allows it. Looking at the docs, this very much seems possible.

https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/list/#types-basic

The example below comes straight from the docs

```
import React from 'react'
import { List } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const ListExampleBasic = () => (
  <List>
    <List.Item>Apples</List.Item>
    <List.Item>Pears</List.Item>
    <List.Item>Oranges</List.Item>
  </List>
)

export default ListExampleBasic
```

So what you want to do is generate an array of components for List.Item. based on the items state you provide. This can be achieved using the .map function.

```
import React from 'react'
import { List } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const RenderList = () => 
  <List>
    {repos.map((item) => RepoListItem(item))}
  </List>

const RenderRepoListItem = item => 
  <List.Item>
    <List.Content>{item.full_name}</List.Content>
  </List.Item>
```

As JSX has an XML-like syntax for compositional components, any children components are nested inside their parent.

Also, I'm not sure where List.Content is coming from, you could probably omit that and just have {item.full_name} directly inside List.Item

Comment: Thanks Carl ! That's the solution I finally used.Anyway I don't understand what this "items" property is useful for. Maybe a shortaround for some cases where you just want to display the description as item ?

Comment: Looks like it will generate the List.Item array of child components for you if you pass it an array of state objects.